# Speed up python loops for the construction of large symmetric matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I wrote this code to create a symmetric matrix m * m (A), where m = 1682. This code runs on a Jupyter NetBook (Ipython) and is very slow. Does anyone know how to improve the performance considering that the real matrix has m = 10 million? 
Other details:

- R is a matrix(numpy array) n*m
- rx is a matrix (numpy array)
- movies is a matrix (numpy array)

  ```
  def make_A(R, rx, movies):
    m = R.shape[1]
    A = np.zeros((m,m))
    for i in range(m):
      for j in range(i,m):
          if i!= j:
              ri = np.linalg.norm(R[:,i], ord=None)
              rj = np.linalg.norm(R[:,j], ord=None)
              mov1 = movies[i]
              mov2 = movies[j]
              temp = rx[(rx[:,1]==mov1) | (rx[:,1]==mov2)]
              temp = temp[:,0]
              y = np.bincount(temp.T)
              ii = np.nonzero(y)[0]
              temp = np.vstack((ii, y[ii])).T
              temp = temp[temp[:,1]==2]
              Uij = temp.shape[0]
              A[i,j]=ri*rj+Uij
    A=A + A.T - np.diag(A.diagonal())
    return A
  ```

Comment: To vectorized those two nested loops and since the second iterator depends on the first iterator, you can use a triangular matrix. It has been discussed here - [`Matrix multiplication with iterator dependency - NumPy`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36045510/matrix-multiplication-with-iterator-dependency-numpy).

Comment: An `m * m` array with `m` = 10 million and double precision (the default) will take about 727 Terabyte of memory.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information but this isn't  a answer for my question

Comment: @devilseven7: user6758673 raised the question because it does not sound the problem is reasonably defined.

Comment: anyway, I look for methods to speed-up some simple computations on symmetric matrices. thx to let me know...