# python vectorization: how to increase the efficiency of 4 layer loop

Tags: python, vectorization, data-manipulation, lda

I am trying to implement LDA using Gibbs sampling and in the step of updating each topic proportion, I have a 4 layer loop and it runs extremely slow and I am not sure how to improve the efficiency of this code. The code I have now is the following:

N_W is the number of words, and N_D is the number of document, and Z[i,j] is the topic assignment (1 to K possible assignments), X[i,j] is the count of the j-th word in i-th document, Beta[k,:] is of dimension [K, N_W].

And the update is the following:

```
for k in range(K): # iteratively for each topic update
    n_k = np.zeros(N_W) # vocab size

    for w in range(N_W):
        for i in range(N_D):
            for j in range(N_W): 
                # counting number of times a word is assigned to a topic
                n_k[w] += (X[i,j] == w) and (Z[i,j] == k) 

    # update
    Beta[k,:] = np.random.dirichlet(gamma + n_k)
```

Comment: Maybe this question will give you some inspiration https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39371021/efficient-loop-over-numpy-array

Comment: Is X and Y a np.array?

Comment: yes, these matrices are np.array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get rid of the last two for loops using logic functions:

```
for k in range(K): # iteratively for each topic update
    n_k = np.zeros(N_W) # vocab size
    for w in range(N_W):
         a = np.logical_not(X-w) # all X(i,j) == w become a True, others a false
         b = np.logical_not(Z-k) # all Z(i,j) == w become a True, others a false
         c = np.logical_and(a,b) # all (i,j) where X(i,j) == w and Z(i,j) == k are True, others false
         n_k[w] = np.sum(c) # sum all True values
```

Or even as a one liner:

```
n_k = np.array([[np.sum(np.logical_and(np.logical_not(X[:N_D,:N_W]-w), np.logical_not(Z[:N_D,:N_W]-k))) for w in range(N_W)] for k in range(K)])
```

Each row in n_k then can be used for beta calculation. Now it also includes N_W and N_D as restrictions, if they are not equal to the size of X and Z

Answer (score 0):

I did some testing with the following matrices:

```
import numpy as np

K = 90
N_W = 100
N_D = 11
N_W = 12

Z = np.random.randint(0, K, size=(N_D, N_W))
X = np.random.randint(0, N_W, size=(N_D, N_W))

gamma = 1
```

The original code:

```
%%timeit
Beta = numpy.zeros((K, N_W))
for k in range(K): # iteratively for each topic update
    n_k = np.zeros(N_W) # vocab size

    for w in range(N_W):
        for i in range(N_D):
            for j in range(N_W): 
                # counting number of times a word is assigned to a topic
                n_k[w] += (X[i,j] == w) and (Z[i,j] == k) 

    # update
    Beta[k,:] = np.random.dirichlet(gamma + n_k)

865 ms ± 8.37 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Then vectorising only the inner two loops:

```
%%timeit
Beta = numpy.zeros((K, N_W))

for k in range(K): # iteratively for each topic update
    n_k = np.zeros(N_W) # vocab size

    for w in range(N_W):
        n_k[w] = np.sum((X == w) & (Z == k))


    # update
    Beta[k,:] = np.random.dirichlet(gamma + n_k)

21.6 ms ± 542 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Finally with some creative application of broadcasting and extracting common elements:

```
%%timeit
Beta = numpy.zeros((K, N_W))

w = np.arange(N_W)
X_eq_w = np.equal.outer(X, w)

for k in range(K): # iteratively for each topic update
    n_k = np.sum(X_eq_w & (Z == k)[:, :, None], axis=(0, 1))


    # update
    Beta[k,:] = np.random.dirichlet(gamma + n_k)

4.6 ms ± 92.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

The trade-off here is between speed and memory. For the shapes I used this was not so memory-intensive, but the intermediate three-dimensional arrays I built in the last solution could get quite large.